# Requests bigger than 8 kb

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, http

I want to evaluate round trip time between client and server. Here the user can choose how big the request/response size of the message (body) should be.  At client side I used Ajax-Post method to send 100 messages in an interval of 100 ms to the http-server. Unfortunatley I got the problem in node.js, that the httpServer.js cannot handle client request sizes of bigger than 8 kb. In this case the variable responseSizeServer in httpServer.js gets the value "undefined" and the console throw an error: "Invalid Array length". The question is why the variable responseSizeServer has got the value undefined ins this case? I suppose that the http-Server.js handle the .end method faster than the incoming request from the client. What do you think and how can it be solved? Thanks in advance :)

Here is the code:

**client:**

```
var i = 0;  
var iterations = 100;
function connectSpeed(){
 run = window.setInterval("startSpeed()", 100); 
 }
function startSpeed()
{
 //Variablen
var requestSizeClient = 8 *1024; // 8 kb request Size client
    var responseSizeServer = 16 * 1024; // 16 kb response size server

var xmlhttp;    

xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("POST","http://localhost:8000", true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
     if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
    var receiveTimeCl = new Date().getTime().toString();
    //evaluate response from httpServer.js
            var message = xmlhttp.responseText;

     }
   }

   //send data to the server
   xmlhttp.send(new Date().getTime().toString() + '#' + new Array((eval(requestSizeClient+1))-(new Date().getTime().toString().length+3)).join('X') + '#' + responseSizeServer);
i++;
if(i==iterations) {
window.clearInterval(run);
i=0;
}
}// end start-speed
```

**server**: (httpServer.js)

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {

var receiveTimeServer;
var clientMsg;
var sendTimeClient;
var responseSizeServer;
var message;

req.on('data', function (chunk) {
    receiveTimeServer = new Date().getTime().toString();
    message = chunk.toString('utf8');
    clientMsg = message.split('#');
    responseSizeServer = parseInt(clientMsg[2]);
    sendTimeClient = clientMsg[0];

res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain','Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*'});
res.end(receiveTimeServer + '#' + new Date().getTime().toString() + '#' + sendTimeClient + '#' + new Array(responseSizeServer).join('X'));
});
  }).listen(8000);
  console.log('Ajax_Server running');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Requests in Node.js are streams, and each `data` event corresponds to an incoming chunk. If the request is big, then multiple chunks are emitted: one can then handle a request while it is being sent, and don't have to wait for the full request to be received before handling it.

In your specific case, what you want is to buffer the full message and then handle it:

```
var message = '';
req.on('data', function (chunk) {
    message += chunk; // concatenate all chunks
});

req.on('end', function() {
    receiveTimeServer = new Date().getTime().toString();
    message = message.toString('utf8');
    clientMsg = message.split('#');
    responseSizeServer = parseInt(clientMsg[2]);
    sendTimeClient = clientMsg[0];
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain','Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*'});
    res.end(receiveTimeServer + '#' + new Date().getTime().toString() + '#' + sendTimeClient + '#' + new Array(responseSizeServer).join('X'));
});
```

You can find a thorough explanation with code samples in [Node.js's streams documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_api_for_stream_consumers).